# Creating dynamic sitemaps with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sitemap

I have somewhere in the region of 60,000 URLs that I want to submit to Google. Given the restriction of 10,000 URLs per file i'm going to need to make a sitemap index and link to at least 6 sitemap files in that index.

I don't know what the most efficient way of doing this is. My idea was to go to my DB, take the `TOP 10000` rows, run my `foreach` on the data and generate my links. My first idea was to create placeholder sitemap files (eg. sm1.xml, sm2.xml, etc.) and after each 10,000 rows increment the file index and insert the next 10,000 into the next file. The problem is that the data in the DB is always being added to, so next month I could have 70,000 URLs - meaning I'd have to create another placeholder file.

So with this in mind, I'd like to create the individual sitemap files dynamically but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Some idea's that might help, you on your way to building a sitemap generator in your project.

- get the urls from your route.php file
- get the classes/methods using the reflections class
- get the data from the database or text file

Loop through each data set like you stated above and create indexed files for them.

use a **CRON** job to index your files via ping.

Use the ping service provided by these search engines.
You should maybe only ping the services at the end of each day or second day,
**don't** ping them once a new row is created!

### Google Ping

http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml

### MSN

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml